# sort a PHP array depending on an explode item

Tags: php, sorting

Completely new to PHP

I need to sort an array that was read in from a text file, line by line

```
$data = fgets($fileHandle);
```

Each $data contains 3 fields, which where exploded with

```
$otherData = explode(',',$data)
```

I need to sort the entire array ($data), by the first item in explode so it would be otherData[0];

from smallest to biggest, the firs item in explode is a number

how do i do this?

some research on google hasn't gotten me very far, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take the column you want to sort as the key of the array. then sort it with `ksort`

```
$data = array();
while($dataLine = fgets($fileHandle))
{
    list($item1, $item2, $item3) = explode(',', $dataLine, 3);
    $data[$item1] = $item3;
}
ksort($data);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: why do i set item1 equal to item3? item3 isn't a number

Comment: it can be anything for `$item3`. you can substitute with `$dataLine` or `array($item2, $item3)`.